# SQL Server: How to specify particular default date format with getdate()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 and one of my tables has a date field. When an insert from my ASP.NET page happens, the date is automatically inserted by setting the default field value to `getdate()`. However, this adds the date in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.0000000`. I really only need the time up to seconds and not the trailing zeros after it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `DateTime`, whether in SQL Server or .NET code **does not have a format**. It has an internal representation.

When you want to *display* the value of the `DateTime` you *format* it using a format string.

Comment: Thanks. I think I was confused between actual data object and format.

Answer (score 2):

```
select (convert(char(19), getdate(), 121))
```

Gives:

> 2012-04-06 10:16:50

Answer (score 0):

Up to SQL Server 2008 R2, all you can do is convert the `datetime` (stored as 8 bytes) you're getting back using a list of possible, supported formats - see the [MSDN documentation on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for the complete list of supported formats.

With SQL Server 2012, you'll be able to use a [`FORMAT` function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/samvangassql/2011/11/29/new-string-function-in-sql-server-2012-_1320_-format_28002900_/) much like in .NET - but again, that's a **new function** in the 2012 version, not available in earlier versions.